# Alias for OFFSET PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table. I need to fetch the ROW_NUMBER for 'pk_ia=3' and 'pk_ib=1' and need to specify that as offset in order to get the rows 'c' and 'd'.

```
Table: items
|pk_ia|pk_ib|data|
|1    |1    |a   |
|2    |1    |b   |
|3    |1    |c   |
|4    |1    |d   |
```

To get row_number, I'm trying to give Alias for offset e.g. `OFFSET some_alias`. I'm getting following error,

```
ERROR:  column "o" does not exist
LINE 1: ...-1) AS o from tblitem ORDER BY pk_iPlu ASC OFFSET o LIMIT 10...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "o" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 266
```

My query is:

```
 SELECT pk_ia, (SELECT row FROM (SELECT pk_ia, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY pk_ia) AS row 
 FROM items where pk_ib=1) AS row_number 
 where pk_ia=(select min(pk_ia) from items where pk_ia >= 3)-1) 
 AS o from items where pk_ib=1 ORDER BY pk_ia ASC OFFSET o LIMIT 10;
```

Expected:
I want something along with offset of 3. i.e., 2

```
 Table: items
|pk_ia|offset|
|3    |2    |
|4    |2    |
```

NOTE: To fetch the next nearest record if the requested 'pk_ia' is not present, I have used,

```
 pk_ia=(select min(pk_ia) from tblitem where pk_ia >= 3)
```

Though the following fetches required result but offset is given as 2 here which is not intended,

```
 SELECT pk_ia, (SELECT row FROM (SELECT pk_ia, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY pk_ia) AS row 
 FROM items where pk_ib=1) AS row_number 
 where pk_ia=(select min(pk_ia) from items where pk_ia >= 3)-1) 
 AS o from items where pk_ib=1 ORDER BY pk_ia ASC OFFSET 2 LIMIT 10;
```

Results in:

```
   Table: items
    |pk_ia|offset|
    |3    |2    |
    |4    |2    |
```

How to get this by using alias?

Comment: This works fine - `SELECT pk_ia from items where pk_ib=1 ORDER BY pk_ia ASC OFFSET ((SELECT row FROM (SELECT pk_ia, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY pk_ia) AS row FROM items where pk_idepartmentidpk_ib=1) AS row_number where pk_ia=(select min(pk_ia) from items where pk_ia >= 1))-1) LIMIT 10;`  Here i need to fetch offset sub query as alias

Comment: This works good and fetches pk_ia. Now i want to use offset value along with it in my result set.

Comment: The subquery in offset results in row value which is given as input for offset. In my sample above, as a result of `SELECT pk_ia` i get pk_ia in my result set. i.e., 3 and 4. I want to obtain offset as well. which is 2. I can also include the same subquery here as, `SELECT pk_ia, <subquery>`  which looks little mess. And yes this will result as rows with 3 2 | 4 2.

Comment: Thank you! since I'm new to Postgres, question might not be self explanatory. I have updated the question. I haven't used fiddle built as a sandbox.

Comment: I dont understand how you get 2... if itsfixed, then just use fixed value?.. eg ```with c(o) as (values(2))
select pk_ia, o from items join c on true where pk_ia > o;```

Comment: 2 is the result of `ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY pk_ia)` where pk_ia is 3. Since it is row number, it varies based on pk_ia value.

Comment: From question -  need to fetch the ROW_NUMBER for 'pk_ia=3' and 'pk_ib=1' and need to specify that as offset in order to get the rows 'c' and 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you try to do is:

```
so=# with c as (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (partition by pk_ib ORDER BY pk_ib) AS row
 FROM items
where pk_ib = 1 and pk_ia >=3)
so-# select pk_ia, max(row) over() from c;
 pk_ia | max
-------+-----
     3 |   2
     4 |   2
(2 rows)
```